# Bluemix SQL Service Access by project contributors in trial version

Tags: sql, ibm-cloud, devops

We are creating a web application for understanding bluemix using a trial version. The team consists of 4 people working on the project using jazzhub. All members can change and commit the code through jazzhub but the sql service is accessible only by the project owner. How do I access the SQL GUI from my end without forking the original owners project or creating a new sql service? Is that something to do with bluemix trial version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To access the SQL Database console, you must have developer access to the organization and space that the SQL database is deployed to. If you add your team members into the organization and space, you can then grant them developer access.